# Update mongodb com node.js não esta atualizando

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

Salve, estou fazendo um crud de update com mongodb, to usando javascript, nodejs, express, handlebars, mongoose e afins. Eu ja procurei por tudo e ja fiz muitas variações, cheguei em uma que parecia certa, pois não da nenhum erro, mas nao atualiza de fato.

A rota é essa:

```
router.post('/categorias/update', (req,res) => {
Categoria.findOne({_id: req.body.id}).then((categoria) => {
        categoria.updateOne(
            {_id: req.body.id},
            {
            nome: req.body.nomeUpdate
            }
        ).lean().then(()=>{
            console.log(`Att`)
            res.redirect("/admin/categorias")
        }).catch((e)=>{
            console.log(`${e}`)
        });
          
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log(`${e}`)
})
```

});

E aqui esta o formulario:

```
{{#categoria}}
<h1 class="mb-4 mt-4">Edite a Categoria</h1>
<div class="card row align-items-center">
    <div class="cord-body">
        <form action="/admin/categorias/update" method="POST" >
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{_id}}">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Nome</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="nomeUpdate" value="{{nome}}" >

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Editar</button>
            
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-success mt-3" href="/admin/categorias/">Voltar</a>
```

{{/categoria}}

Comment: Não seria `Categoria.updateOne(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose provê um método de busca e atualização mais eficiente e minimalista `findOneAndUpdate`, no seu caso pode fazer algo como:

```
  Categoria.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.id }, { nome: req.body.nomeUpdate })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(`Att`);
      res.redirect("/admin/categorias");
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(`${e}`);
    });
```